# Headlamp Replacement

Tags: car

I had a fender bender in my 2015 Chevy Equinox LTZ.  I've taken very good care of my truck.  It only has 35533 miles.   The lights and the fog lights all worked perfectly.  The bezel was broken. (If I'm typing this correctly)  The repairman replaced the whole headlamp and fog light with aftermarket parts that look like they were bought at Wally World. The high beam looks the same on both headlamps.  The low beam is brighter on the headlamp that was replaced.  I took it back to the repairman who alleged didn't see the difference. Would replacing the other original bulb help and/or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the bulb is a different rating, or could be the old reflector is poor, or it could be the wiring to the old side has a poor connection. You need to find out which.